# How to output rsync sent data in realtime using standard tools

Tags: terminal, rsync, progress-information

I'm developing a small tool for some people who need to send files over to a server.
I'd like to use rsync to a rsync deamon to do so.

Is it possible to have rsync to output how much data it has actually sent (uncompressed)?
I'm not speaking about the final stats, I would like them to be realtime as rsync is sending the data.

Note : Rsync doesn't support the --info tag on any of the available versions on my OS

Comment: I get rsync: --info: unknown option

Comment: rsyncing 2.6.9 from a mac to a centOS with rsync 3.1  just updated rsync on the mac, well let you know

Comment: updated to 3.0.7 still unknown option..

Comment: Doubtful. I think you should mention in your question that your system's `rsync` doesn't support `--info` on any available version. I'll wipe out my comments, since they aren't useful.

Comment: `--progress` might fulfill your demands?

Comment: Try `--stats`. And update to rsync 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

(Current as of `rsync-3.1.2`)

The `--progress` option will give you a running log of exactly what's going on while transferring data.  Larger files will be displayed with an ETA time, transfer speed etc.

> `--progress`
>
> This option tells `rsync` to print information showing the
>             progress of the transfer. This gives a bored user something to
>              watch.  [...]

You may also want to try `--info=progress2` which works like `--progress` but display information about the whole transfer rather than for individual files.